# On top how to display Another layout in android

Tags: android, layout

Hi in the below code On top of that want to add one more layout .but I don't no how to add and where to add can any one help me with the issue.
What I am expecting is background name with boreder_square that background want to display between above and below of the layouts

[between two layout I want to add one more layout middle can any one help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4ToF.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/back_blue"
        android:id="@+id/contact_card"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
    
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="center"
            android:background="@color/linecolor"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" >
    
            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:id="@+id/accountfrg">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:paddingBottom="100dp">
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:padding="2dp"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:orientation="vertical">
    
                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="120dp"
                                android:layout_height="120dp"
                                android:tint="@color/white"
                                android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_check_24"
                                ></ImageView>
                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/subject"
                                style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/names"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:text="Booking Confirmed"
                                android:textAllCaps="true"
                                android:textColor="@color/white"
                                android:textSize="18sp"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />
    
                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/speclist"
                                style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/names"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:text="Confirmation mail and SMS has been sent to your registered details"
                                android:textAllCaps="false"
                                android:textColor="@color/white"
                                android:textSize="16sp" />
    
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="430dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/border_square"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                        android:gravity="bottom">
    
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="0dip"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:gravity="center|bottom"
                            android:orientation="vertical">
                            <Button
                                android:id="@+id/book_appointment"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
                                android:background="@drawable/button_background"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:text="Done"
                                android:textColor="@color/white" />
    
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
   
            </ScrollView>
        </FrameLayout>
    
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve can be done very easily with ConstraintLayouts.
To achieve such a layout with LinearLayout is going to have a negative performance on your UI.

You can use two constraint layouts to achieve this.

[Learn about constraint layouts here](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout?authuser=1)

Have a parent constraintlayout that has the imageview of the tick and the textview,then inside it have another constraint layout that has a background with a white drawable with topright and left corners of around 100dp. And a button inside the inner constraint layout.

MainLayout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:background="#fff">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="BOOKING CONFIRMED"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView6" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Confirmation mail and sms has been sent to your registered details"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView9" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_width="227dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/success" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:background="@drawable/sample_sam"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView10">

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

sample_sam.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <corners android:topRightRadius="50dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="50dp"/>
    <solid android:color="#000"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: I want one more layout want to display

Comment: I used three constraint layout still layout is not working fine